# How can I customize Source Resolver in Media Foundation

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I want to customize Media Foundation's [Source Resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would like to play files encrypted with DRM, and the extension is AVI, MPEG4 and possibly other.

How can I customize Source Resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic ways of customization are documented in [Scheme Handlers and Byte-Stream Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The source resolver can create a media source from a URL or from a byte stream [...]. For URLs, the source resolver uses scheme handlers. For byte streams, it uses byte-stream handlers.
> [...]
>
> To register a new scheme handler, add an entry whose name is the CLSID of the scheme handler, [...]
>
> To register a new byte-stream handler, add an entry whose name is the CLSID of the handler, [...]

Comment: No, I not required change to ByteStreamHandler.